# add a row in custom ListView and get the data from intent.putExtra()

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a custom `listView` that is empty in first time , from other side i have an activity which contains a product details such as picture, title, model .in this activity there is a `button` , so when user press this button i want to add the product into my custom `listView` and shows all the product details there,

my `listView` is:

```
public class ListViewShoppingBasketActivity extends Activity {
BaseAdapter adapter;

ArrayList<SingleRow> list;
Context context;
String[] titles;
Bitmap[] images;
String[] descriptions;

TextView title;
TextView description;
ImageView image;

String rowTitles;
String rowDescription;
Bitmap rowImage;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.list_view_shopping_basket_layout);

    final ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    list.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(this));

    list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position,
                long id) {

            if (id == 0) {
            } else if (id == 1) {

            } else if (id == 2) {

            } else if (id == 3) {

            } else if (id == 4) {

            }

        }
    });

}



class SingleRow {
    String rowTitles;
    String rowDescription;
    Bitmap rowImage;

    public SingleRow(String rowTitles, String rowDescription, Bitmap rowImage) {
        this.rowTitles = rowTitles;
        this.rowDescription = rowDescription;
        this.rowImage = rowImage;
    }

}

class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    public MyAdapter(Context c) {
        context = c;
        list = new ArrayList<SingleRow>();



    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {

        return list.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {

        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.shopping_basket_listview_row,
                viewGroup, false);

        title = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        description = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        image = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

        SingleRow temp = list.get(i);

        title.setText(temp.rowTitles);
        description.setText(temp.rowDescription);
        image.setImageBitmap(temp.rowImage);

        return row;
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.list_view_shopping_basket, menu);
    return true;
}

// // **********baraye add kardane item jadid be listview
public void addItems(View v) {
    list.add(new SingleRow(rowTitles, rowDescription, rowImage));
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}


    }
```

and this is implementation of my `button` in other activity

```
        b_add_to_cart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b_add_to_cart);
    b_add_to_cart.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(BarcodeDetailsActivity.this,
                    ListViewShoppingBasketActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("productID", proId);
            intent.putExtra("productModel", proModel);
            intent.putExtra("productTitle", proTitle);
            intent.putExtra("productPictureUrl", mIcon11);

            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
```

my problem is , i dont know how and where i can assign my product details in my listview

Comment: so, where is the problem?

Comment: @MarkoNiciforovic Im dont know how to show (assign) my product details in my listview

Answer (score 0):

You can put the next lines to the code of the ListViewShoppingBasketActivity:

```
Intent i = getIntent();
if (i.getExtras() != null){
    int prodId = i.getExtras().getInt("productID");
    ....
}
```

You can put theese to an ArrayList, and use an BaseAdapter (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html) to display the data in the list.